# Cannot find the declaration of the element 'RelativeLayout'

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, github, android-relativelayout

I took an android project from GitHub and cloned it to my Android Studio. When I am trying to run the ActivityMain.xml file in order to check if the project works correctly I'm getting this error "Cannot find the declaration of the element 'RelativeLayout'" . I dont know how to solve this. If anyone has any other way of running the project pls suggest that too.

The link of the github file is given below

https://github.com/PedroCarrillo/Expense-Tracker-App

Comment: can you paste the most important part of your code?

Comment: The code is very long and there are several XML files 

You may lookup the link given for the entire project 

The error I am getting is in this location

Expense-Tracker-App/ExpenseTracker/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: My fault, I didn't explain. Please have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: So here's the thing , I am having errors in every XML file where I have used Relative or Linear layout 

One of the XML file is given in this link - https://notepad.pw/bhav1234

Answer (score 0):

All the layout files should be under layout directory in project